# Subscribe/unsubscribe user from mailchimp list after purchase

Tags: emails

I am using mailchimp 7.x 3.3 Module and ubercart is integrated for role selling,
also I have rules module installed.

I have users subscribed to the mailchimp list, my requirement is when a user from my list purchase any order he should be unsubscribed from one list and subscribed to other mailchimp list, so that I can track the users from the list who did not purchase any order.

I am thinking of doing it using rules, In rules I have an event "when the user completes checkout", I want to add the action on same event, the action should be "unsubscribe from one list and subscribe to other list" but unfortunately I dont have any way to select the list there.

Please find the screenshot of rules interface below, help would be greatly appreciated.

This is event interface
[image]

This is Action Interface

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because MailChimp doesn't want you to just subscribe people without their permission, it makes you put this into a field.

We have clients, however, who put the subscription opt-in into their Terms of Use agreement. A way around this is to create your own rule:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Rules integration for the mailchimp lists module.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_rules_action_info().
 */
function mymodule_rules_action_info() {
  $items = array();
  $items['mailchimp_lists_id_user_subscribe'] = array(
    'label' => t('Subscribe or unsubscribe entity from a MailChimp list ID'),
    'parameter' => array(
      'entity' => array(
        'type' => '*',
        'label' => t('Email Address'),
        'description' => t('The email to subscribe.'),
        'wrapped' => TRUE,
        'allow null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'list_id' => array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => t('MailChimp List ID'),
        'description' => t('The list ID found in the mailchimp dashboard.'),
        'allow null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'subscribe' => array(
        'type' => 'boolean',
        'label' => t('Subscribe'),
        'description' => t('True to subscribe, False to unsubscribe'),
      ),
    ),
    'group' => t('MailChimp'),
    'access callback' => 'mailchimp_lists_rules_access_callback',
    'base' => 'mymodule_rules_action_entity_subscribe',
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Action callback: Subscribe an entity to a list.
 */
function mymodule_rules_action_entity_subscribe($entity, $list_id, $subscribe) {
    $email = $entity->value();

    $choices = reset($field_info['instance']['default_value']);
    $choices['subscribe'] = $subscribe;

    if ($subscribe == 1) {
        mailchimp_subscribe($list_id, $email);
    } else {
        mailchimp_unsubscribe($list_id, $email);    
    }
}
```

Where *mymodule* is the name of your custom module. This will provide the rule integration you're actually looking for.

Be careful, though: This method could get you banned from Mailchimp. It's best to combine it with a double opt-in process to prevent people from reporting subscription abuse.